# JavaScript Hoisting declaration confusion when using Immediately-invoked function expression

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend, hoisting

Get confused.

```
var message = "Xinrui Ma";

var call = (function(){
    message = "I am cool";
})();

alert(message);
```

From my perspective, the code will be treated like this:

```
var message = "Xinrui Ma";

var call = (function(){
    var message;         // it will add message declaration here
    message = "I am cool";
})();

alert(message);        // this should alert the "Xinrui Ma", not the "I am cool", 
                       // cause Hoisting is JavaScript's default behavior of moving all declarations 
                       // to the top of the current scope
```

But in fact, it outputs "I am cool", why is that????

Comment: The second snippet will alert "Xinrui Ma".

Comment: You're confused about hoisting. Hoisting never adds a `var` which was not there.

Comment: Because `message` is a global variable? It has nothing to do with IIFE btw, only with how scope works. Whether you used an IIFE or separate the function declaration and execution, doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have a variable declaration inside a function, it uses the variable from the containing scope. It doesn't create a new local variable -- there wouldn't be any way to refer to closure variables if it did that.

This has nothing to do with hoisting, which only occurs when you declare the variable in the function. Hoisting would apply if you wrote:

```
var call = (function() {
    message = "I am cool";
    var message;
})();
```

In this case, the `var` declaration would be hoisted to the top of the function.

Answer (score 1):

`var` keyword is used to create a local scope, by default it uses the global scope. Hence message here points to global scope and you are modifying it in IIFE.

You can prevent that using

```
var message = "Xinrui Ma";

var call = (function(){
    var message = "I am cool";
})();

alert(message);
```